# Spring Boot AMQP based JmsListener fails on TextMessage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have a Spring Boot application which has problems retrieving JMS messages of type `TextMessage` from an ActiveMQ broker.

If the consumer tries to retrieve messages from the broker it cannot automatically convert a message to TextMessage but treats it as ByteMessage. There is a JmsListener which should read the messages from the queue as TextMessage:

```
...
@JmsListener(destination = "foo")
public void jmsConsumer(TextMessage message) {
...
```

The `JmsListener` produces warnings like the following, and drops the messages:

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method could not be invoked with incoming message
Endpoint handler details:
Method [public void net.aschemann.demo.springboot.jmsconsumer.JmsConsumer.jmsConsumer(javax.jms.TextMessage)]
Bean [net.aschemann.demo.springboot.jmsconsumer.JmsConsumer@4715f07]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [[B] to [javax.jms.TextMessage] for org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@7c49d298, failedMessage=org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener$MessagingMessageConverterAdapter$LazyResolutionMessage@7c49d298
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:118) ~[spring-jms-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

I have extracted a small sample application 
 to debug the problem: https://github.com/ascheman/springboot-camel-jms

The producer in real life is a commercial application which makes use of Apache Camel. Hence, I can hardly change/customize the producer. I have tried to build a sample producer which shows the same behavior.

Could I somehow tweak the consumer to treat the message as `TextMessage`?

Besides: Is there any way to retrieve the additional AMQP properties from the message programmatically directly in Spring? Of course, I could still read the message as `ByteMessage` and try to parse properties away. But I am looking for a cleaner way which is backed by any Spring API. The Spring `@Headers` annotation didn't help so far.

Comment: You are receiving a `byte[]` and that by default gets converted to a `ByteMessage`. I would suggest to either just receive the `byte[]` and not message with specific JMS typed messages. Try `String` instead of `TextMessage`. Properties aren't headers (AFAIK) so not sure where they get mapped to in this scenario. If you really want to use a `TextMessage` write a custom message converter to convert a `byte[]` into a `TextMessage`.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not about changing the type: I can get the `byte[]` contents as well as a `String`. However, in this case the message also contains some additional data - so called properties (check out the mentioned AMQP spec. for details). I am interested in the genuine text message which was originally sent by the producer. I would not like to parse it from the `byte[]` or `String` object myself.

I expect to get a correct JMS object if the used transport is JMS compatible, not a number of bytes which I need to handle myself.

Comment: But you aren't using JMS as the transport, that is the main problem as you are using AMQP. You are basically tunneling JMS through AMQP (which is different from JMS). So messages are adapted and the `TextMessage` will get converted to something that AMQP understands, which if you look at the Java API is a `byte[]`. Fact is you aren't using JMS but rather AMQP which you try to shoehorn into JMS. Why not simply use AMQP instead?

Comment: Is this really AMQP, or ActiveMQ (AMQ)? You can receive `Message<?>` instead, which is a spring-messaging abstraction over multiple transports (including JMS). It has a `payload` and `headers` (which are mapped from the JMS message).

Comment: Hmm, to my understanding, JMS is only an API at first hand, as is JDBC. It is often mapped to an underlying MOM implementation, ActiveMQ in this case. The wire protocol is AMQP but it could also be something different (The ActiveMQ broker speaks different protocols on different ports: defaults to 5672 + 61616). 

The message itself even says it has JMS type 5 (`TextMessage`) in the ActiveMQ properties. So why not convert it correctly?

Let's say we want to stay as close to the JavaEE standard _JMS_ as possible.

I think it might even be a failure in either Spring or ApacheMQ?

Comment: To avoid people wasting their time, this question was also [cross-posted](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15827) as a Spring Boot issue. My suspicion is that it's a broker configuration problem with the default `native` mapping being used rather than the desired `jms` mapping. See https://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html for details on the various mapping options.

Answer (score 0):

I ever faced the same issue with the question owner, after I followed the comment from @AndyWilkinson by adding **transport.transformer** option on the transportConnector in **activemq.xml** as the following, the issue is solved.

```
<transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;transport.transformer=jms"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and it was caused because `LazyResolutionMessage` is called from `MessagingMessageConverter` that is the default implementation to `MessageConverter`, [which converts your message](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/listener/adapter/AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java#L544) (actually it doesn't, since it's the default):

```
return ((org.springframework.messaging.Message) payload).getPayload();
```

I have accomplished what you want, at the end my consumer was working like:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${someName}")
public void consumeSomeMessages(MyCustomEvent e) {
  ....
}
```

What I had to do was:

```
@Bean(name = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory whateverNameYouWant(final ConnectionFactory genericCF) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(t -> log.error("bad consumer, bad", t));
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setConnectionFactory(genericCF);
    factory.setMessageConverter(
            new MessageConverter() {
                @Override
                public Message toMessage(Object object, Session session) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("since it's only for consuming!");
                }

                @Override
                public MyCustomEvent fromMessage(Message m) {
                    try {
                      // whatever transformation you want here...
                      // here you could print the message, try casting,
                      // building new objects with message's attributes, so on...
                      // example:
                      return (new ObjectMapper()).readValue(((TextMessage) m).getText(), MyCustomEvent.class);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    return factory;
}
```

A few keypoints:

1. If your `DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory` method is also called `jmsListenerContainerFactory` you don't need `name` attribute at `Bean` annotation
2. Notice you can also implement an `ErrorHandler` to deal with exceptions when trying to convert/cast your message's type!
3. `ConnectionFactory` was a Spring managed bean with Amazon's `SQSConnectionFactory` since I wanted to consume from a SQS queue. Please provide your equivalent correctly. Mine was:

   ```
   @Bean("connectionFactory")
   public SQSConnectionFactory someOtherNome() {
       return new SQSConnectionFactory(
               new ProviderConfiguration(),
               AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                       .withCredentials(
                               new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                                       new BasicAWSCredentials(
                                               "keyAccess",
                                               "keySecret"
                                       )
                               )
                       )
                       .build()
       );
   }
   ```

Answer (score -2):

If you have a problem with conversion from byte[] to String use:

```
.convertBodyTo(String.class)
```

Route example:

```
from(QUEUE_URL)
                .routeId("consumer")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .log("${body}")
                .to("mock:mockRoute");
```

Comment: I am not using and not willing to use Camel on the consumer side.